# Migrating magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I copied a magento 1.9 installation from one host to a new. Then when I try activating the new installation I get a database error:

```
SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'testadmin'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

#0 /var/www/html/magento-development/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(111): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()
#1 /var/www/html/magento-development/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(396): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#2 /var/www/html/magento-development/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(460): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->_connect()
#3 /var/www/html/magento-development/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#4 /var/www/html/magento-development/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(504): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SET NAMES utf8', Array)
#5 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(179): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('SET NAMES utf8')
#6 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource.php(110): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->_newConnection('pdo_mysql', Object(Mage_Core_Model_Config_Element))
#7 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(320): Mage_Core_Model_Resource->getConnection('core_write')
#8 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(350): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getConnection('write')
#9 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Abstract.php(335): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getWriteAdapter()
#10 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Cache.php(53): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Abstract->_getReadAdapter()
#11 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(478): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Cache->getAllOptions()
#12 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php(520): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->_initOptions()
#13 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1202): Mage_Core_Model_Cache->canUse('config')
#14 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(414): Mage_Core_Model_App->useCache('config')
#15 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(294): Mage_Core_Model_Config->_canUseCacheForInit()
#16 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(424): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadModulesCache()
#17 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initModules()
#18 /var/www/html/magento-development/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#19 /var/www/html/magento-development/index.php(84): Mage::run('', 'store')
#20 {main}
```

Can I reinstall or just set the db password somewhere?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Copied to Local WAMP server, Exception: SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1045\] Access denied for user](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1526/copied-to-local-wamp-server-exception-sqlstatehy000-1045-access-denied-for)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database credentials are found in `app/etc/local.xml`

Set them to the login name, password and database on the current machine.

The section you're looking for looks like this:

```
    <resources>
        <db>
            <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
        </db>
        <default_setup>
            <connection>
                <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                <username><![CDATA[namehere]]></username>
                <password><![CDATA[passhere]]></password>
                <dbname><![CDATA[dbnamehere]]></dbname>
                <active>1</active>
            </connection>
        </default_setup>
    </resources>
```

This is assuming you have already gone into cPanel or phpMyAdmin and created a user account, created a database, assigned the user to the database and imported your database contents.